# How to create custom script for import products in magento

Tags: php, magento, import, magento-1.7

I am working on magento 1.8 version.

I need to create custom script or extenson for import product from my custom csv file which have some different fields.

Comment: If my answer was correct, please mark it. thx

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use OS Magmi, is much more faster than script an is simple to configure and periodical run.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

You can also create a script which can you run.

1. you need to get data from csv file to memory
   2 convert them to array
   3 list array for each product
   4 in foreach loop save or update product.

Some basic script:

```
<?php


$max_i = 20000; // maximal ammount


chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); /
//error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
//ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600000);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Prague');
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}


$time_start = microtime_float();



//////// SKU from CSV
$csv = file_get_contents ('yourcsvfile.csv'); 

function parse_csv ($csv_string, $delimiter = ";", $skip_empty_lines = true, $trim_fields = true)
{
    $enc = preg_replace('/(?<!")""/', '!!Q!!', $csv_string);
    $enc = preg_replace_callback(
        '/"(.*?)"/s',
        function ($field) {
            return urlencode(utf8_encode($field[1]));
        },
        $enc
    );
    $lines = preg_split($skip_empty_lines ? ($trim_fields ? '/( *\R)+/s' : '/\R+/s') : '/\R/s', $enc);
    return array_map(
        function ($line) use ($delimiter, $trim_fields) {
            $fields = $trim_fields ? array_map('trim', explode($delimiter, $line)) : explode($delimiter, $line);
            return array_map(
                function ($field) {
                    return str_replace('!!Q!!', '"', utf8_decode(urldecode($field)));
                },
                $fields
            );
        },
        $lines
    );
}
// list to array
$vystup = parse_csv($csv);
$seznamsku = array();
foreach ($vystup as $sku) {
  array_push($seznamsku, $sku[0]);
  unset($seznamsku[0]);    
  $seznamskufin = array_filter($seznamsku, 'strlen');  
};



require("../../app/Mage.php");
echo "START ".date('h:i:s')."\n\n";
Mage::init();

// Set an Admin Session
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(1);
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setUser($userModel);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());



$pocet = 1;

foreach ($seznamskufin as $item) {  




    echo "\n number(".$pocet.")..sku(".$item.")..";              


    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$item);              

    if(is_object($product)) { //if is product exist in Magento            










            if (empty($product->getShortDescription())) {  // if is value empty
                $product->setShortDescription($ZboziDetail['info']);  // write to magento
                echo "..(importing)..";
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "..(skipped)..";    // exists
            };






                      $product->save();                          // save to magento

                       echo "..saved";



      } else { echo ".(skiped)"; };


                  unset($item);
                  unset($product);
                  unset($ZboziDetail);
                  unset($product_imageUrl);
                  unset($newimage);
                  unset($e);
                  $pocet++;                                
};

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo " \n\n All done in ".$time." seconds."; 


$logfile = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($logfile, $seznamskufin);
fclose($logfile);  

unset($response);
unset($vystup);
unset($seznamsku);
unset($seznamskufin);
?>
```

Comment: Multiple patterns are using the `s` modifier with no actual effect on the pattern.  `\s` only affects the dot metacharacter.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest and safest way is to create a simple script (outside Magento) that transforms your csv to the csv structure used for import in `System->Import/Export->Import`.

TO see the format of the csv you need go to `System->Import/Export->Export` and export your current products.